# ScriptResource.axd:5Uncaught TypeError: Object function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I ve pages which use UpdatePanel and randomly I get an error:

ScriptResource.axd:5Uncaught TypeError: Object function Function() { [native code] } has no method '_registerScript'

registration.aspx:67Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined

It only happens on the production environment where are 3 server loadbalance.

But on each of this servers as I tried there was a sittuation when error was and no.

What is going on ?

Comment: Seems like it could be a cache issue?

Answer (score 3):

Your Javascript function embedded in ScriptResource.axd has no method `_registerScript` is going on.

You don't specify what .NET or ASP.NET version you are using, so I am not sure if this is due to the changes in ASP AJAX .NET 4 or not, like the related StackOverflow question in the resources links below.

Though from the fact that it is `ScriptResource.axd`, you probably have something like 
`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource` or `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`, which you don't want in an ASP Update Panel, use  `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead.

General things to be aware of with regards to ScriptResource.axd and web farms include

- The patch level and dlls on all hosts are the same. Related [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718413/webresource-axd-throwing-exceptions-in-web-farm)
- The machine key for validation and decryption is the same host. Relevant [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480392/invalid-viewstate-for-scriptresource-axd), specifically **jesal**'s answer.
- The loading of the ScriptResource.axd based on the caching due to the timestamp parameter.
  See [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/358509/scriptresource-axd-urls-for-gac-assemblies-flawed-in-web-farm-environments-due-to-time-stamp-parameter) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/358509/scriptresource-axd-urls-for-gac-assemblies-flawed-in-web-farm-environments-due-to-time-stamp-parameter)

Relevant resources include

- [Related StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725094/updated-asp-net-3-5-to-4-0-sys-webforms-pagerequestmanager-is-undefined)
- [Understanding ScriptResource and WebResource in ASP.NET](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2008/07/28/understanding-scriptresource-and-webresource-in-asp.net.aspx)
- [Not working ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript with Update Panel](http://forums.asp.net/t/1229586.aspx/1)
- [HOWTO: Write controls compatible with UpdatePanel without linking to the ASP.NET AJAX DLL](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2006/11/13/HOWTO_3A00_-Write-controls-compatible-with-UpdatePanel-without-linking-to-the-ASP.NET-AJAX-DLL.aspx)
- [Call JavaScript from an ASP.NET AJAX Update Panel in Content Page Load](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/04/call-javascript-from-aspnet-ajax-update.html)
- [ASP.NET AJAX : Update Panels and Register Script Woes](http://harindaka.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/aspnet-ajax-update-panels-and-register.html)
- [UpdatePanels and ClientScript in custom Controls](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Dec/12/UpdatePanels-and-ClientScript-in-custom-Controls)